# Changelly: confirmation of BTC/ETC transaction although ETC never arrived

Tags: ethereum-classic, bitcoin

Recently, I used Changelly to exchange BTC for ETC. Inadvertently, I made a mistake typing in the address of my ETC wallet (a 3 instead of a 2). Changelly informed me that the 'transaction is complete', nevertheless, I have no ETC in my wallet. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you've had Ethereum tokens sent to an address that you don't control, you're out of luck, the tokens are lost. Unless, by mere happenstance this other address is also in use (which is unlikely to an astronomical degree). Unfortunately, Ethereum addresses don't have a checksum as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks fro your input. It was a relatively small amount, nonetheless, this will serve as a costly lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're almost certainly out of luck.

Your ether has already been sent to the incorrect address. With this technology there's no reversal progress.

I hope for your sake this was a small amount and you can use this as a learning experience going forward.

In the future I would highly recommend copy and pasting address when possible and then making sure you copied the correct address before making any transaction.

Answer (score 1):

We are sorry to hear about the mistake occurred. Unfortunately, our team has no authority to remove or reverse any operation from the wallets, since we don't have the credentials or empowerments for it. If money has already been transferred, the process becomes irreversible. This is how blockchain works. 
Hence we do recommend to check all the details attentively before sending the funds.

Also, we may suggest you contact the appropriate party (the support team of ETH wallet) and provide them with required information on the matter occurred.